# Is it possible to use MySQL trigger to access DB2

Tags: mysql, db2, database-trigger

I have two tables. One is in MySQL and the other is in DB2. The table in MySQL will be periodically modified and I want to define a trigger in MySQL to synchronize the data between MySQL and DB2. Is it possible?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible, given enough time and resources. Now, what's your actual question?

Comment: How to build a DB2 connection inside a MySQL trigger? Can we give me an example? As far as I know, the MySQL federated table can only be used for MySQL database.